# Check if value exists in array and update or push input data

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I've tried following several other forum posts that seem to address my same question but none of them work for me. I'm passing values from a button click on an html page into an array. If the first value of the array exists in the array already I want to update the other 4 values in the array. If it does not exist I want it to create a new row of data. I can get the new rows to be created but the checking of the value in the array will not work. I had been trying to use angularJS and datatables to accomplish this but abandoned that approach after reading some posts that those don't work as well together. One other thing if I get the code to execute the "here" alert it throws it 5 times. It should just alert once, so I'm assuming if it was updating the table it would be doing it 5 times, and that doesn't make sense. Thanks in advance!

```
var arrayTable = [{busId: "", xCord: "", yCord: "", eventType: "", timeStamp: ""}];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );

function fnUpdateRow(t, r, e, w, q) {
    arrayTable = [t, r, e, w, q];
    var addToArray = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayTable.length; i++) {
    if(arrayTable[i].busId == t) {
        addToArray=false;
        arrayTable[i] = ({busId:t, xCord:r, yCord:e, timeStamp:w, eventType:q});
        alert("here");
        }
    }
    if(addToArray) {
        $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData(arrayTable);
            alert("here2");
        }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using an array, why not use an object whose key is the `busId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reasigning `arrayTable` at the beginning of the function, that's wrong. Break out of the loop when you find the match. And you're updating the dataTable, but you're not adding to `arrayTable` when you don't find a match.

```
function fnUpdateRow(t, r, e, w, q) {
    var addToArray = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayTable.length; i++) {
        if(arrayTable[i].busId == t) {
            addToArray=false;
            arrayTable[i] = ({busId:t, xCord:r, yCord:e, timeStamp:w, eventType:q});
            alert("here");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(addToArray) {
        var newRow = {busId:t, xCord:r, yCord:e, timeStamp:w, eventType:q};
        arrayTable.push(newRow);
        $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData(newRow);
        alert("here2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the response. The break; solved the repeating issue. However, the if statement still always returns false. So it always drops down and executes the code before alert "here2". I'm passing a static set of values so I should see it add the row once with alert "here2" then be catching and alerting "here". But it never thinks arrayTables[i].busId is a match even though it is. Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: I just noticed that you're overwriting `arrayTable` in the first line of your function. Take that out.

Comment: Well that solved my issue of the loop not matching values. I get the correct order of alerts now. But now I get an error message saying "DataTables warning (table id = 'example'): Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 1" So the data is getting updated to the array now but not updating on the table. Sorry I'm for so many questions. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I can see whats happening the $('#exmape').dataTable()fnAddData() line seems to be the issue cause it's trying to add the whole array not just the new passed values. But I can't seem to find the correct syntax for it.

Comment: BTW, after you replace `arrayTable[i]` in the upper `if`, don't you need to do something to `dataTable()` to tell it about the change?

Comment: Good morning, unforutnately I am still getting the same error message with the "newRow". I see what you are talking about as well with the upper if statement. I'll make sure to add in something to update the change. Just trying to get one thing working at a time. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, I was able to solve this with this line  $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData([t, r, e, w, q]); Apparently I needed to add in the []. For some reason though using the variable newRow or arrayTable wouldn't work.